# How to print variables values in Robotframework log

Tags: robotframework

I have a RF test and I need to print the variables values, not the name.
I am trying with "**log to console  Num:  ${Num}**" but log.html only shows:

```
**KEYWORD** BuiltIn . Log To Console Num:, ${Num}
Documentation:  
Logs the given message to the console.
Start / End / Elapsed:  20170209 12:14:05.273 / 20170209 12:14:05.273 / 00:00:00.000
```

I already tried to setting log level (TRACE, DEBUG) but didn't work.
I appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: I think, you have didn't give tab space between `Log To Console` and `${Num}` give that try

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try using keyword "Log"

```
Log    Num value is ${Num}
```

Comment: Adding `console=yes` will ensure it is visible on the console.

Comment: @Surreal Dreams, "Adding console=yes": where?

Comment: @Coliban Append it (leaving 2 spaces): `Log  Num value is ${Num}  console=yes`

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone still looking for how to print to console,  simply use:

Log To Console   Hello World

or

Log To Console   ${Variable}

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

As of `robotframework` 5.0.1 the command is now:

```
Log  "Num value is ${Num}"  console=True
```

See http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log